# VB.net Get Primary key of row that has just been updated

Tags: vb.net

I have an update statement and i wanted to know how i could get the primary key of the row i just updated.

```
SELECT @@identity
```

I tried this but it didn't work.
I keep on getting 0.

But my update statement could be the problem aswell because in not sure about it either.

```
    UPDATE payment INNER JOIN booking SET hire_cost=" & cost(1) & ",additional_cost=" & cost(0) & ",total_cost=" & cost(2) & ",Deposit=" & Math.Round(cost(2) / 4) & " WHERE booking.bookingID='" & y & "' AND payment.PaymentID=booking.PaymentID
```

Please help!

Comment: Just added or just updated?  If you just updated it, you should have the key.  Which database are you working with?

Comment: Can you please post your code (vb.net and/or sql)?

Comment: That's good for insert when you have no way of knowing the primary key. When you do an update, just do a select statement with the same where clause as the update (you can do the select before or after the update depending on what you are updating).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify your column in the database as an identity column for it to return anything other than 0